# How to create part of a rainbow gradient

Tags: delphi, colors, gradient

I need to generate a gradient bitmap that displays a rainbow gradient between two colors which are chosen by a user. To generate a rainbow is easy. The code below I got from [Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Theory/Color_gradient) and slightly adapted it. It has the advantage of being fast and simple.

```
 function TColor_Dialog.GiveRainbowColor (fraction: double): TAlphaColor;
  var
    m: Double;
    r, g, b, mt: Byte;
  begin
    if fraction <= 0 then m := 0 else
    if fraction >= 1 then m := 6
                     else m := fraction * 6;
    mt := (round (frac (m) * $FF));
    case Trunc (m) of
    0: begin
        R := $FF;
        G := mt;
        B := 0;
      end;
    1: begin
        R := $FF - mt;
        G := $FF;
        B := 0;
      end;
    2: begin
        R := 0;
        G := $FF;
        B := mt;
      end;
    3: begin
        R := 0;
        G := $FF - mt;
        B := $FF;
      end;
    4: begin
        R := mt;
        G := 0;
        B := $FF;
      end;
    5: begin
        R := $FF;
        G := 0;
        B := $FF - mt;
      end;
    end; // case

    Result := ColorToQuad (r, g, b);
  end; // GiveRainbowColor //
```

Trouble with this algorithm is it can't show a partial rainbow between two colors. Well, of course it can but than you have to approach the fraction of each color and I don't like that solution. I tried decomposing the color into its r, g, b channels but that did not work. The reason is quite obvious by hindsight. Suppose you need a gradient between FF0000 and 0000FF. You'll have a red color transforming from FF->00 and a blue from 00->FF. However, there is no green (00FF00) which is clearly present in a rainbow gradient.

What I need is a gradient function that I can give two colors and a fraction and it generates a color. Can anyone point me to an article, algorithm or even code?

**Update**

NGLN's answer is the right answer for this question. Both he and Warren wondered what to do when a a color is not a *bright* color (a color containing a 0, a $FF and a value). I tried several angles: up/downscaling and HSL interpolation. I finally settled down for the last one as being the most simple.

Basically you have two colors: `from` and `to`. Use RGBtoHSL to extract the HSL parameters from each color: `RGBtoHSL (col_from, hf, sf, lf)`. Next compute the hue, saturation and luminance between both colors and reconstruct a new color. This is what NGLN mentions in his update about hue, but if you generalise this principle you have a rainbow between any color.

```
function TColor_Dialog.interpolate_hsl (col_from, col_to: TAlphaColor; fraction: double): TAlphaColor;
  var af, at, ad: uInt8;
      hf, ht, hd: single;
      sf, st, sd: single;
      lf, lt, ld: single;
  begin
  // Get each rgb color channel
     af := GetAValue (col_from);
     at := GetAValue (col_to);
     RGBtoHSL (col_from, hf, sf, lf);
     RGBtoHSL (col_to,   ht, st, lt);

  // Compute differences
     ad := af + Round (fraction * (at - af));
     hd := hf + fraction * (ht - hf);
     sd := sf + fraction * (st - sf);
     ld := lf + fraction * (lt - lf);

     Result := MakeColor (HSLtoRGB (hd, sd, ld), ad);
  end; // interpolate_hsl //
```

This gives a rainbow for all colors possible. I apply the same interpolation for the opacity, hence the use of `MakeColor` to 'fumble' the interpolated alpha channel into the color.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what result you are after?

Comment: @kobik, assuming [`this is`](http://i.imgur.com/w3SFuid.png) the rainbow gradient, [`this could be`](http://i.imgur.com/oDM51uz.png) the gradient range OP is talking about.

Comment: What I don't understand is what format you want to have the input colors in? TColor? And if so, what happens when you input a color that is not on, or even near the color gradient. Remember that there are a lot of R,G,B pair values that are NOT on the 100%-saturated-spectrum of hues, at a given brightness? Do you want to walk towards the spectrum and then travel along it?

Comment: @warren, good point. NGLN in his answer points to the same problem. I'd not given it a thought I must confess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then you need to calculate the position of a color in the Rainbow; the inverse of `GiveRainbowColor`:

```
function RainbowIndex(BrightColor: TColor): Double;
var
  R: Byte;
  G: Byte;
  B: Byte;
begin
  R := GetRValue(ColorToRGB(BrightColor));
  G := GetGValue(ColorToRGB(BrightColor));
  B := GetBValue(ColorToRGB(BrightColor));
  if (R * G * B <> 0) or ((R <> 255) and (G <> 255) and (B <> 255)) then
    Result := -1
  else if B = 0 then
    if R = 255 then
      Result := 0 + G / 255
    else
      Result := 1 + (255 - R) / 255
  else if R = 0 then
    if G = 255 then
      Result := 2 + B / 255
    else
      Result := 3 + (255 - G) / 255
  else { G = 0 }
    if B = 255 then
      Result := 4 + R / 255
    else
      Result := 5 + (255 - B) / 255;
  Result := Result / 6;
end;
```

*(But this displays a problem for colors not having both a 0 and a 255 part. In other words: you would also need to calculate the bright color from a shaded, tinted or grayed color. See update below.)*

Example usage to get the rainbow slice from `clRed` to `clBlue`:

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Start: Double;
  Finish: Double;
  X: Integer;
begin
  Start := RainbowIndex(clRed);
  Finish := RainbowIndex(clBlue);
  for X := 0 to ClientWidth - 1 do
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := GiveRainbowColor(0, ClientWidth - 1, X);
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds(X, 0, 1, 50));
    Canvas.Brush.Color :=
      GiveRainbowColor(0, ClientWidth - 1, Round(Start + (Finish - Start) * X));
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds(X, 50, 1, 50));
  end;
end;
```

### Update:

The `RainbowIndex` routine above really does nothing more then calculate the [hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) property of the color. The `GraphUtil` unit provides conversion routines for the [HSL color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Disadvantages) which makes this `RainbowIndex` routine kind of obsolete and gives the advantage to be able to feed any `TColor` value:

```
uses
  GraphUtil;

const
  HLSMAX = 240;

function Hue(AColor: TColor): Double;
var
  Hue: Word;
  Luminance: Word;
  Saturation: Word;
begin
  ColorRGBToHLS(ColorToRGB(AColor), Hue, Luminance, Saturation);
  Result := Hue / HLSMAX;
end;
```

Example usage to get the rainbow slice from `clMoneyGreen` to `clPurple`:

[image]

```
function RainbowColor(Hue: Double): TColor; overload;
begin
  Hue := EnsureRange(Hue, 0, 1) * 6;
  case Trunc(Hue) of
    0: Result := RGB(255, Round(Frac(Hue) * 255), 0);
    1: Result := RGB(255 - Round(Frac(Hue) * 255), 255, 0);
    2: Result := RGB(0, 255, Round(Frac(Hue) * 255));
    3: Result := RGB(0, 255 - Round(Frac(Hue) * 255), 255);
    4: Result := RGB(Round(Frac(Hue) * 255), 0, 255);
  else
    Result := RGB(255, 0, 255 - Round(Frac(Hue) * 255));
  end;
end;

function RainbowColor(MinHue, MaxHue, Hue: Integer): TColor; overload;
begin
  Result := RainbowColor((Hue - MinHue) / (MaxHue - MinHue + 1));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;
  Start: Double;
  Finish: Double;
begin
  Start := Hue(clMoneyGreen);
  Finish := Hue(clPurple);
  for X := 0 to ClientWidth - 1 do
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := RainbowColor(0, ClientWidth - 1, X);
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds(X, 0, 1, 50));
    Canvas.Brush.Color :=
      RainbowColor(Start + (Finish - Start) * X / ClientWidth);
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds(X, 50, 1, 50));
  end;
end;
```

Furthermore, the RainbowColor routine could be shortened to:

```
function RainbowColor(Hue: Double): TColor; overload;
begin
  Result := ColorHLStoRGB(Round(Hue * HLSMAX), HLSMAX div 2, HLSMAX);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will test this in the evening. You raise the same question as warren and I have no answer yet. Maybe I should try another color model like HSV.

Comment: It took me some time before I realised why your solution at first didn't work for me. You appear to use some  sligtly different version of GiveRainbowColor. To have an inverse for GiveRainbowColor for my situation I need a function that returns a value between 0..1. I get that by omitting the '/6' from each assigment and dividing the final result by 6. And indeed it doesn't solve the problem of not having both 0 and 255. But I think I can rescale each color to something between 0..255, remember the scaling value and next downscale the result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great extension! I independently just used the HSL model to compute the saturation and luminance as well so the algorithm can computer a rainbow like gradient between any (?) two colors. Just see the update. I'll adopt your changes into a final algorithm :-)

Comment: Adjusted my update with new code. It now has become an amazingly simple routine and very versatile :-)